# Javascript round number to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, number-formatting

I have a little problem that I can't seem to get my head round...

I have figure that I need to find what the VAT element of it would be, I have the following jQuery which works but it doesn't fix it to 2 decimal places.

```
var ThreeMonthPriceFinal = "99.29";
var ThreeMonthPriceVAT = ThreeMonthPriceFinal * 0.2.toFixed(2);
alert(ThreeMonthPriceVAT);
```

It works out the VAT correctly but adds lots of recurring digits that i don't need... I can't round it up as with VAT you not really supposed to.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg4Qs/

The Jfiddle shows £19.858000000000004 I need this to show 19.86, i've tried the following but it rounds it up to the whole amount not just 1p.

```
var ThreeMonthPriceVAT = Math.round(ThreeMonthPriceFinal * 0.2).toFixed(2);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: that's... not jquery...

Comment: Just add brackets like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg4Qs/4/

Comment: Not jQuery, but in the same context.

Comment: This looks more like: http://vanilla-js.com/ :)

Comment: Sorry guys added to the wrong tag... :-(

Comment: Sorry what a simple question... thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Remember to check answer which was right! :)

Comment: A few suggestions:
- you should probably avoid using Uppercase variables for things that are not constructors or at the very least objects
- "99.29" is NOT the same thing as 99.29: since you're working with numbers, you should write them as numbers. "99.29" is a string that gets implicitly cast as a number in your case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic of parentheses

```
var ThreeMonthPriceVAT = (ThreeMonthPriceFinal * 0.2).toFixed(2);
```